# Can the EVM execute code from memory?

Tags: evm, memory, static-call

To my understanding `address(addr).code` and `memory[...]` are in different places and since code memory is read-only, a usual `call` doesn't seem to be able to achieve this, but is there any other way to e.g. execute code passed as function parameter?

```
function execute(bytes calldata _code) {
    magically_call(_code)
}
```

I mean theoretically one could implement an EVM bytecode interpreter, but that would be quite an expensive contract...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amplifying @Ismael's answer,you could achieve the effect by deploying contracts with the code to run, and running in a proxy that accepts a contract address and uses delegate call to execute the arbitrary function. There would be a deployment cost for each arbitrary code instance and, of course, the main contract would plainly do literally anything, casting more than a little doubt on any assurances about what it actually does.

Check out "diamond pattern" for inspiration.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, thanks! That sounds better than an on-chain interpreter :D Note to self: [Diamond Pattern](https://dev.to/mudgen/understanding-diamonds-on-ethereum-1fb)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

You could deploy the bytecode as a new contract and then execute it.